# Open source FHIR server recommendation needed

Tags: server

I am looking for an open source [FHIR server](https://build.fhir.org/http.html).

I want to set up a general purpose server that will be able to handle whatever requirements come up later. FHIR is used for so many purposes, it's hard to say any particular requirements up front and even if I could we'd probably use the server for something different later anyway.

Some factors I know are important are performance and scalability, security, maintainability and ease of migrating to a new database later.

Please say why your suggestion is better than popular alternatives if possible.

#FHIR #healthcare